# Regular expressions, is it always true that (r+s)*=r*+s*?

Tags: algorithms, regular-expressions

I'm really confused about this, can some one please help me understand this better.

> If r and s are regular expressions then is it always true that (r+s)*=r*+s*?

Are r and s sets and does the plus mean the union?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R$ be the set of words described by the regular expression $r$, and let $S$ be the set of words described by the regular expression $s$. Then the regular expression $(r+s)^*$ describes the words in the set $(R\cup S)^*$, and $r^*+s^*$ describes the words in the set $R^*\cup S^*$. Thus, the question boils down to asking whether it’s necessarily true that $(R\cup S)^*=R^*\cup S^*$. (Looking at some very simple regular expressions should give you the answer pretty easily.)

Comment: so say r = {0} and s = {1}

Comment: does that mean that essentially r + s in this case is any number of repetitions of 01?

Comment: @Supernatural: Make that $r=0$ and $s=1$; $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are then the sets $R$ and $S$, respectively. (The point is that the braces have no place in the regular expressions. // No, $r+s$ is then $0+1$, which represents the two-word set $\{0,1\}$. To get any number of repetitions of $01$, you’d use $(01)^*$.

Comment: for two general expressions to be the same they have to generate the same language right?. if i take a word 01, this can be generated by (r+s)* but not by r*+s*, because r* or s* could contain nothing right?

Comment: @Supernatural: Yes, $01$ can be generated by $(0+1)^*$; $0\in R$ and $1\in S$, so $01\in(R\cup S)^*$. And yes, it’s not generated by $0^*+1^*$, but not because $0^*$ and $1^*$ generate the empty string: the empty string **is** generated by $(0+1)^*$. $01\notin R^*\cup S^*$ because the $R^*$ contains only strings of $0$’s (including the empty string), and $S^*$ contains only strings of $1$’s (including the empty string), and $01$ is neither.

Comment: I understand the union bit (i've done set theory) but how does the star come into play? i've always thought about it as any number of repetitions

Comment: @Supernatural: It is: for regular expressions $r^*=\epsilon+r+rr+rrr+\ldots$, and for regular sets $R^*=\varnothing\cup R\cup R\oplus R\cup R\oplus R\oplus R\oplus\ldots$, where $\oplus$ stands for concatenation.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailes explanation!

Comment: @Supernatural: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

$r$ and $s$ are regular expressions, which represent regular sets.  If $r$ and $s$ are regular expressions that represent sets $R$ and $S$, then the regular expression $r+s$ denotes the set $R\cup S$.

If $r$ is a regular expression denoting the set $R$, then $$r^*$$ is a shorthand for $$\epsilon + r + rr + rrr + \cdots .$$